# before collapse and before expand events in fieldset extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are using fieldset in our application using extjs3.Now we are moving forward to extjs4.So beforeexpand and beforecollapse are not working in extjs4.Is there any chance to use these or else any replacement to these events.Please help me.I am searching a lot for these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are no such events but it's easy to create them by yourself. Here's my fieldset which extends original one and has requested events:

```
Ext.define('MY.fieldset', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    alias: 'widget.myfieldset',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.addEvents('beforeexpand', 'beforecollapse');
        this.callParent([arguments]);
    },
    setExpanded: function(expanded){
        var bContinue;
        if (expanded)
            bContinue = this.fireEvent('beforeexpand', this);
        else
            bContinue = this.fireEvent('beforecollapse', this);
        if (bContinue !== false)
            this.callParent([expanded]);
    }
});
```

**And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/nz37z/1/) is working example.**

Comment: Hi Molecule, i have an another doubt.If we click on search button,the first row in the grid has to select?how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Kiran, I didn't check, but I guess You have to put something like 'grid.getSelectionModel().select(0)' in button's onclick handler

Comment: yeah i tried grid.getSelectionModel().select(0), grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().select(0),grid.view.getSelectionModel().focus(0). But no improvement.If you have any idea,please help me.

Comment: It will work for button in bbar.If we specify button separately and if we write this code in click handler of that button,it is not working.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. It [must](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/2BhfY/5/) work